# How to make the wp-admin access from a different subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, custom-wordpress-pages, wp-admin

------- Technologies I'm using ---------

- Debian 10
- Nginx server
- PHP8.0

--------- The scenario ------------

I have exmaple.com which has an HTML static website
and I have a subdomain, blog.example.com I installed WP on it and it's working fine
but I want to make the wp-admin access on login.blog.example.com.

-------- What I tried -------------

1- I tried redirecting any /wp-* URL to login.blog.example.com, but that isn't useful if there are no files/folders of wp-admin on login.blog.example.com.

2- I followed this, but it wasn't handy since they are redirecting to 404 and a static page
https://403.ie/how-to-serve-wp-admin-from-a-separate-subdomain/

-------- The nginx configuration -----------

example.com:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name IP_ADDRESS;
        return 301 http://example.com;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

blog.example.com:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name blog.example.com;

        root /var/www/blog.example.com;
        index index.html index.php index.htm;

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

#       location /wp-admin{
#               rewrite ^/wp-(.*)$ http://login.blog.example.com redirect;
#       }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

Comment: What is your server configuration for `blog.example.com` and `login.blog.example.com`?

Comment: I added example.com and blog.example.com to the post
I didn't create login.blog.example.com yet.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create a server to handle requests to `login.blog.example.com`. This is identical to `blog.example.com` except for the `server_name` and any "login" bits you want to add.

Then add a redirect in the `blog.example.com` server block:

```
location ^~ /wp-admin { 
    return 302 $scheme://login.blog.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

WordPress may insist on redirecting you back to `blog.example.com`. This is because of the settings for [site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) in the Dashboard configuration or the `wp-config.php` configuration file.

You should be able to drop the hostname from the HOME and SITEURL values and use `/` instead of `http://blog.example.com`.

Comment: I followed exactly your instructions and it's redirecting to login.blog.example.com/wp-admin/
but I'm getting an 500 internal server error

Comment: The reason for those errors should be reported in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I'd suggest this:

```
location ~ ^/wp-admin { 
    return 302 $scheme://login.blog.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

As far as I know the ^ char is supposed to go before the regular expression, according to UNIX REGEX standards.

So now the expression sounds like "whatever uri starts with /wp-admin"

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**